# Get text from matplotlib's TextBox and save to a file

Tags: matplotlib, textbox

How can I get the text from a matplotlib's TextBox?
I have this:

```
(...)
ax_info = plt.axes([0.7, 0.7, 0.2, 0.25])
info_box = TextBox(ax_info, label='', initial='INFO:')
```

and then, when a button is pressed I have the following function:

```
def get_info(text):
    info = text
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(directory, 'info.txt'), info)


info_box.on_submit(get_info)
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't seem to be getting the text from the text box, but rather the step where you save the text to a file.

[`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) expects an array-like object to save to a file, and also by default expects the values to be as floats (you can change this if necessary).

To keep using `np.savetxt`, you must first make your string "array-like", and then we need to specify that the format is a string, not a float, for example:

```
def get_info(text):
    # make info a list, so it is array-like
    info = [text]
    
    # specify format as a string
    np.savetxt(os.path.join(directory, 'info.txt'), info, fmt="%s")
```

If you are just writing one line to a text file, however, you could probably just use the built-in python IO functionality, rather than numpy. Something like:

```
def get_info(text):
    info = text
    
    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'info.txt'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(info + '\n')
```

Comment: The problem isn't there because I tried to print the info string and I get nothing.

Comment: Interesting. The TextBox part works for me, and I can print the info string with no problem. Perhaps you could create a [MCVE] and provide details of how you are running this

Comment: I managed to make it work by getting the text this way: self.info_box.text

Comment: But you were indeed correct and afterward, I got the error regarding the saving part. So thank you!